# What country are the text pranksters supposed to be from?

Tags: community

In Community Season 6 Episode 3, some unknown schoolkids are kidding the principal into thinking he has Jeff Winger's mobile number and that he's texting him.

The Schoolkids look Oriental but what country are they supposed to be from, the skyline in the background looks like some generic skyline and they have a buddha like statue on the shelf and they are wearing formal schoolwear.

Can anyone identify the country? It looks like Hong Kong but it maybe a different country.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it seems the kids were Japanese and the city was supposed to be Tokyo:

[image]

[image]